# Move element in perl array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an element in an array that I'd like to move accordingly.

```
@array = ("a","b","d","e","f","c");
```

Basically I'd like to find the index of "c" and then place it before "d" again based on "d"'s index. I'm using these characters as an example. It has nothing to do with sorting alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this using *array slice* and `List::MoreUtils` to find array elements indexes :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

# help to find an array index by value
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);

my @array = qw/a b d e f c/;

# finding "c" index
my $c_index = firstidx { $_ eq "c" } @array;

# finding "d" index
my $d_index = firstidx { $_ eq "d" } @array;

# thanks ysth for this
--$d_index if $c_index < $d_index;

# thanks to Perleone for splice()
splice( @array, $d_index, 0, splice( @array, $c_index, 1 ) );

say join ", ", @array;
```

See   [splice()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)

### OUTPUT

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Comment: Bonus for `firstidx`. :) How about splicing the original array? `splice( @array, $d_index, 0, splice( @array, $c_index, 1 ) );`

Comment: From the docs for delete. `delete() may also be used on arrays and array slices, but its behavior is less straightforward. Although exists() will return false for deleted entries, deleting array elements never changes indices of existing values; use shift() or splice() for that. However, if all deleted elements fall at the end of an array, the array's size shrinks to the position of the highest element that still tests true for exists(), or to 0 if none do.` It happened to work for your example because 'c' was at the end of the array.

Comment: Have to pop in again! If 'c' precedes 'd' your nested `splice` may fail (I think). ysth's solution fixes this. Nice use of `firstidx`.

Comment: Added `--$d_index if $c_index < $d_index;` thanks Chris Charley & ysth

Answer (score 4):

```
my @array = qw/a b d e f c/;
my $c_index = 5;
my $d_index = 2;

# change d_index to what it will be after c is removed
--$d_index if $c_index < $d_index;
splice(@array, $d_index, 0, splice(@array, $c_index, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's my shot at it  :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/ first /;

my @array = ("a","b","d","e","f","c");
my $find_c = 'c';
my $find_d = 'd';

my $idx_c = first {$array[$_] eq $find_c} 0 .. $#array;
splice @array, $idx_c, 1;

my $idx_d = first {$array[$_] eq $find_d} 0 .. $#array;
splice @array, $idx_d, 0, $find_c;

print "@array";
```

This prints

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl t33.pl
a b c d e f
```

Comment: And you should test whether an index was found for 'c'. If not found, `first` would return `undef`.

Comment: from the problem statement, it sounds like the indexes are the input, not the values; that's why I didn't include finding the index in my answer

Answer (score 0):

U can try this

```
my $search = "element";
my %index;
@index{@array} = (0..$#array);
 my $index = $index{$search};
 print $index, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` to insert an element at a specific index in an array. And a simple for loop to find the indexes you seek:

```
my @a = qw(a b d e f c);
my $index;

for my $i (keys @a) { 
    if ($a[$i] eq 'c') { 
        $index = $i; 
        last; 
    } 
} 

if (defined $index) { 
    for my $i (keys @a) { 
        if ($a[$i] eq 'd') { 
            splice @a, $i, 1, $a[$index];
        } 
    } 
}

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \@a;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c',
          'e',
          'f',
          'c'
        ];
```

Note that this code does not remove the `c` element. To do that you need to keep track of whether you insert the `c` before or after `d`, since you are changing the indexes of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using array slices.  This assumes you know the desired of the elements in the array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(a b d e f c);
print @array;

my @new_order = (0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4);
my @new_list = @array[@new_order];

print "\n";
print @new_list;
```

See this link to [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564363) for details.